# Collisions in `std::unororder_set<std::string>`

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-set

I would like to model collisions in `std::unordered_set<std::string>` in C++. 
Where I can find an implementation of 64 bits hash function for `std::string`?

Comment: You might be interested in the bucket api.

Comment: I believe each vender potentially has their own version of hash function. Or at least can do so. So you might get different answers for different compilers. Microsoft recently made their whole STL open source and moved it to GitHub (or in the process of doing so...)

Answer (score 1):

The source code for [clang](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) and [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc) will have the default hash function for `std::string`.

Comment: I guess I need to look somewhere here: [link](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std), but it is not so easy.. A lot of templates